# Complex conjugations

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I'm stumped on an equation from a coursera course (Intro to DSP) that has to do with complex exponential multiplication:
[image]

In line 2, by simple rules of complex multiplication, it should be (h+k). I understand it being (h-k) has to do with complex exponential conjugation but not really sure why/how.
Any help understanding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex conjugate of a complex number written as $re^{i\theta}$ where $r,\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by $(re^{i\theta})^* = re^{-i\theta}$.  Since we're taking the complex conjugate before multiplying, we have $$(e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk})^*e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nh} = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nh} = e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)n}. $$

Comment: "convex conjugate" -> "complex conjugate".  The use of ${}^*$ for complex conjugate is common in physics; but not in mathematics, where an overbar $$\overline{e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}}$$ is used.

Comment: My bad, I meant to write "complex conjugate;" not sure why I wrote convex conjugate instead.  Fixed now!